# Shot Matcher for CS6 works for video?

Tags: adobe

Adobe SpeedGrade CS6 support Shot Matcher for video ? i found it is support in CC, no one mention in CS6

http://creativeclouduser.com/speedgrade-cc-shot-matcher/